# Initialize an ActiveRecord instance using a parameter not on the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The User model has an id column that is used all throughout your schema, but you'd like to create other models using the username rather than the id:

```
User.create!(username: "phillip")
User.create!(username: "joe")
Message.create!(from_username: "phillip", to_username: "joe", message: "hello")
```

Here, 'from_username' and 'to_username' don't actually exist on the table. Rather, there is a 'from_id' and 'to_id'. You can add 'from_username' and 'to_username' as methods to the model, but then you can't create a new Message using them.

What is the recommended way to add these 'virtual attributes' to a model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Most idiomatic way

You could define a custom `create` function, like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_from_usernames(from_username, to_username)
    from_user = User.find_by_username(from_username)
    to_user = User.find_by_username(to_username)
    self.create(from_user: from_user, to_user: to_user)
  end
end
```

### Making call-site code handle this itself

This is still somewhat idiomatic, but not very DRY.

```
from_user = User.find_by_username("phillip")
to_user = User.find_by_username("joe")
Message.create!(from_user: from_user, to_user: to_user)
```

### Using `create` directly

This is not really recommended, but you could do something like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :from_username, :to_username

  before_create :find_users

private
  def find_users
    self.from_user = User.find_by_username(from_username)
    self.to_user = User.find_by_username(to_username)
  end
end
```

This leads to somewhat "magical" behavior though, and there should be more error checking / handling if you're going to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably use your attr_accessor example. The intended use is a form where people enter a username to send a message to. It seemed appropriate for the model to know the different ways it can be created rather than the controller. Your approach would allow me to 'Message.create!(params)' in the controller.

Comment: The `create_from_usernames` example would work too, you'll just have to extend it a bit to accomplish the same thing as `create`.

Comment: You're probably right. I can take a variable number of keyword arguments in create_from_usernames, and pass the unprocessed remainder onto create. And it would be clearer that this isn't built-in behavior. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal way to do that would be to include these attributes into your Message model. So instead of saving the user_id you can also save the user_name. Otherwise, just work around it and get the username by the user_id. May be I did not fully understand your question, though..